# CakePHP 3.8: How to use uasort() in a Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to use the [uasort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function in a CakePHP Controller.

I have a txt file containing a filename in each line.
The filename has the format SOME_TEXT_YY.MM.DD_HH-MM_SOME_TEXT
I want to sort the files after the given Date and save them again therefore I have written this php code which works correctly using plain php:

```
<?
// compare function
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $a1 = explode('-', $a);
    $a2 = explode('S', $a1[1]);
    $ac = substr($a1[0], -11,11).$a2[0];
    $b1 = explode('-', $b);
    $b2 = explode('S', $b1[1]);
    $bc = substr($b1[0], -11,11).$b2[0];
    if ($ac == $bc) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($ac < $bc) ? -1 : 1;
}
$files = file("files.txt");

uasort($files, 'cmp');

file_put_contents('sorted.txt', $files);

foreach ($files as $line) {
    echo $line."</br>";
}
?>
```

When I am trying to run this in an Controller Function in CakePHP it somehow does not work.
I assume it is because of the "nested" function.
Does someone know how to get this to work inside of a Controller?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

The Error I get is

> Warning (2): uasort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'cmp' not found or invalid function name [APP/Controller/KeysController.php, line 123]

```
class KeysController extends AppController {
[...]
public function update() {
 $dir = WWW_ROOT . 'data';
 $files_filename = $dir . DS . "files.txt";
 function cmp($a, $b) {
                $a1 = explode('-', $a);
                $a2 = explode('TVOON_DE', $a1[1]);
                $ac = substr($a1[0], -11,11).$a2[0];
                $b1 = explode('-', $b);
                $b2 = explode('TVOON_DE', $b1[1]);
                $bc = substr($b1[0], -11,11).$b2[0];
                if ($ac == $bc) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return ($ac < $bc) ? -1 : 1;
            }
            $otrkeys = file($files_filename);

            uasort($otrkeys, 'cmp');

            file_put_contents($files_filename, $otrkeys);
            echo "sortiert";
 }
}
```

Comment: Does not work in what way? Do you get any errors? Are the lines not sorted properly? Does it not save the results?

Comment: The whole file is unsorted like it was before.

Comment: Can you show us the controller action?

Comment: I added the code Line 123 is "uasort($otrkeys, 'cmp');"

Comment: If you're not using `cmp` elswhere (and it doesn't seem like you do), define it directly in the `uasort` as an anonymous callback and try again.

Comment: Not that it's a good idea to create functions like that in the first place, but you are creating a function in a namespace, and aren't including that namespace in the name that you're passing to `uasort()`, hence the error.

Comment: These kind of operations should never be inside a controller in the first place. Always put them at least in a component, maybe even further down into business classes (e.g. through Service Layer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @El_Vanja's suggestion will work, it's less than ideal in the case where you need to re-use that same function in multiple controller actions.

Per the [documentation on callables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), "A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1". So, you could do this with `uasort($otrkeys, [$this, 'cmp']);`.